# Looping through indices in array by 3s

Tags: python, arrays, list

I am attempting to create a function that check to see if the sum of three consecutive numbers in an array are equal to 7.

The first three indices in the list seem to work. However, my `for` loop does not continue throughout the entirety of the list. How do I resolve this?

```
def seven(array):
    three = []
    count = 0

    for num in array[count::count+3]:
        three.append(num) 

        if sum(three) == 7:
            return True
            break
        else:
            count += 1
            continue

print(seven([1,1,5,0,6,1]))
```

Comment: you're exiting after the first 3 because they meet the condition. Maybe you need a yeild to return true

Comment: its not clear what you expect to happen for `1,1,5,0,6,1` do you expect to check  `[1,1,5],[1,5,0],[5,0,6],[0,6,1]` ? or do you just expect to check  `[1,1,5],[0,6,1]` ?

Comment: When it finds that the first 3 in the list = 7, then it returns true, meaning the def is finished...

Comment: The `continue` and `break` statements are unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the array you are iterating over is created just once - on the beginning of iteration.

```
def seven(array):
    for i in range(len(array)-2):
        three = array[i:i+3]
        if sum(three) == 7:
            return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through your array by steps of 3 using python's `range` method. `range(0,len(array)-2,3)` will go from 0 to 3 less than the total length of the array, adding three after each pass

Then, in your call to `sum()`, you can use array splitting to get the sum of the next 3 objects

```
def seven(array):
        three = []
        count = 0

        for num in range(0,len(array)-2,3):
            three.append(num) 

            if sum(array[num:num+3]) == 7:
                return True
        return False
    print(seven([1,1,5,0,6,1]))
```

Comment: And you have to subtract 2 instead of 3. If you put 3 then for example for array of length 3 you would perform 0 iterations.

Comment: @ Piotr Thanks, fixed now